# Python Curses start_color() error

Tags: python, colors, curses

First let me preface this with I am just learning this library and am trying to get this working and will clean it up in later iterations.

That said my code is throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cursesDemo1.py", line 30, in <module>
    box3 = maketextbox(1,40, 10,20,"foo",deco="underline",textColorpair=curses.color_pair (0),decoColorpair=curses.color_pair(1))
_curses.error: must call start_color() first
```

I am not sure where I would need to call `start_color()` and I can't seem to find any examples of this error on google nor a way to fix it.

I have tried adding it everywhere and am stumped can anyone please give me some guidence on where to look or an example?

Here is my full code:

```
import curses 
import time

screen = curses.initscr()

def maketextbox(h,w,y,x,value="",deco=None,underlineChr=curses.ACS_HLINE,textColorpair=0,decoColorpair=0):
    nw = curses.newwin(h,w,y,x)
    txtbox = curses.textpad.Textbox(nw)
    if deco=="frame":
        screen.attron(decoColorpair)
        curses.textpad.rectangle(screen,y-1,x-1,y+h,x+w)
        screen.attroff(decoColorpair)
    elif deco=="underline":
         screen.hline(y+1,x,underlineChr,w,decoColorpair)

    nw.addstr(0,0,value,textColorpair)
    nw.attron(textColorpair)
    screen.refresh()
    return txtbox

 try:
    screen.border(0)

    box1 = curses.newwin(22, 50, 3, 5)
    box1.box()   

    box2 = curses.newwin(22, 50, 3, 65)
    box2.box()   

    box3 = maketextbox(1,40,  10,20,"foo",deco="underline",textColorpair=curses.color_pair    (0),decoColorpair=curses.color_pair(1))
    textInput = box3.edit()

    box1.addstr(2, 18, "Functions")
    box2.addstr(2, 18, "Processes")

    screen.refresh()
    box1.refresh()
    box2.refresh()
    box3.refresh()

    for i in range(19):
        toWrite = "Does this move run = %d" % i
        box1.addstr(8, 9, toWrite)
        box1.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
        box2.addstr(8, 9, textInput)
    screen.getch()



finally:
    curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Call start_color right after you call initscr.

IE:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = curses.initscr()
    screen.start_color()
    ...
    screen.endwin()
```

Eric S. Raymond's "Writing Programs with ncurses" is an excellent general introduction to the low level screen management portion of the library.  You don't need to know C to understand it as the library functions pretty much map directly to their Python counterparts on a 1:1 basis:

http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Also: http://tinyurl.com/lgkyggq because invariably the fist thing people ask about is how to properly implement scrolling and a good portion of that book deals with the subject.

Answer (score 0):

in my case(python 2.7), this code fixed my problem:

```
curses.start_color()
```